# Increase/decrease ticks and grid lines amount on view resize

Tags: macos, core-plot

I'd like to re-arrange axis ticks/labels/grid lines the user resizes the view.

When view grows big it can show more details, and when it shrinks it ends overlapping all the labels.

I'd expect such an auto arrange from the Automatic labelling policy, but it looks like it doesn't.

**What is the best place to hook or method to override in the CorePlot graph to process resize/redraw?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Core Plot layer fires a `CPTLayerBoundsDidChangeNotification` notification when its `bounds` change. Add a notification observer to the graph and adjust the labeling parameters (desired number of ticks, etc.) as needed.

Comment:  I would never find it by myself.